# What does "That stick through they man through the BS with" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, slang, lyrics

I'm concerned with the second line of the first verse of "By a Stranger" by Black Rob:

> We came to give love to our die hearted real bitches
>   That stick through they man through the bullshit with

It is clearly grammatically incorrect, but I would like to understand its meaning and rewrite in grammatically correct form.

It feels like it should have been written:

> That stick to their men through the bullshit with

Comment: don't know if it's grammatically incorrect in the dialect of the singer/songwriter. it's not standard English, though. it's also lyric, which means it could be English *at play*, not conforming to any dialect

Comment: @green_ideas _it's also lyric, which means it could be English at play, not conforming to any dialect_ Does this make it impossible to recover a grammatically correct version?

Comment: it often makes "grammatical analysis" of lyrics off topic, because we can't properly "analyze" art ...and lyric, which is poetry, can often be read many ways, so yeah what the "grammatically correct" version is meant to be is anyone's guess

Comment: You are quite right. If you listen to the actual recording you will hear *stick **to** their man*. It's a mistranscription, possibly due to [*homophony*](https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Homophone) or [*dittography*](https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Dittography).

Comment: I've several times run across lyrics online which are obviously mistranscribed.  In many cases lyrics online are "contributed" by people listening to the works, vs coming from the song's score, and often they are careless.

Answer (score 4):

I listened to that part of the song a few times on YouTube. I don't think the lyrics you've quoted are quite what he's saying in the recording. I know some lyrics websites quote the same words as you, but those websites aren't completely reliable, sometimes they just publish a random internet user's idea of what the lyrics seem to be.

I believe he is saying:

> We came to give love to our die-hearted real bitches
>
> That stick to their man through the bullshit (with)
>
> Good lovin' and good fuckin' all night long...

I hear it as "stick to their man" quite clearly, not "stick through they man".

I think the "with" at the end of the second line that I've put in parentheses is actually the first word of the next line, but the rhythm of his rapping sort of gives the impression that it's the end of the second line.

So it's not as grammatically incorrect as you thought.

The first two lines could be paraphrased as follows:

> We give love to our loyal and authentic women
>
> Who remain faithful to their men throughout life's trials

Comment: Speaking of incorrect lyrics, to me the first line sounds like "We **get** to give love ..."

Comment: @user1420956 - I listened to that line again, and I think you are right. That word didn't sound as clear to me as the rest of those lines, and I think "came" makes more sense, but then he's using a dialect that I'm not very familiar with, and you've convinced me on what it sounds like. I'll update that word in my answer.

Comment: @KannE Now I don't even know... Sometimes it sounds as "get", sometimes as "came".

Comment: @KannE - Okay, I'll take your word for it. I've rolled back my edit.